# Jquery on focus event delegation

Tags: jquery

For some strange reason this simple function doesn't seem to work:

```
$("body").on("focus", this, function(){
    alert('d');
})
```

`this` is input or textarea element.

If i were to do this:

```
$(this).on("focus", function(){
    alert('d');
})
```

It would work on those elements that exists at the moment, but i event would not fire up on newly created elements, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: show more code so we can see what  `this` is

Comment: Really need to see more code, this isn't much to go on. if `this` is an input field, it would lead me to think that the surrounding function is an event handler itself?

Comment: Second parameter must be a `selector`, not `element`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter is, as described by the API, **"a selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event."**

I assume `this`, in your case, is a DOM element. Try changing that to a selector to match inputs or textareas. This will cause your function to be called whenever a `focus` event bubbles up to `body` from an element matching your selector. This should work for you:

```
$("body").on("focus", "input, textarea", function() {
    alert('d');
});
```

Further information on `on()` here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Okay this works, but it targets all textareas and inputs in my entire website while i need to target just some specific elements, and `this` is a DOM element, i get it by running small jquery plugin with `each` function.

Comment: You can change the selector to be more specific. For example, if the elements you want to listen to all have the class `foo`, you can use `$("body").on("focus", "input.foo, textarea.foo", function { ... });`, or if they're all within an element with id bar, `"#bar input, #bar textarea"` should do the trick. If there isn't yet already a way to select them like that, you can add a class to the inputs and textareas when you create them and use that in the selector.

Comment: Well it really surprises me that i have to use selector and not element it self, it makes things so much harder when working with hundreds of classes at once... but it seems to be working so i guess i'll have to stick with it for now.

Comment: You can, of course, bind your event handler to each individual element, like so: `$(this).focus(function() { ... });`, but as you noted in your question, this will only apply to `this`. You would just have to bind the handler to each newly created element.

Answer (score 1):

As @grantman16 has mentioned that the second parameter must be a selector,

But If it's a newly created element why don't you use [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

```
​va​r input = $("<input>");
input.focus(function() {
  alert('d');
});
$("body").append(input);​
​
```

[Example -1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut3Jp/)

You don't need to use `.on`, but if you are insistent to use it, you should set a selector as second parameter,

```
var input = $("<input>").addClass("lastInput");
$("body").on("focus", "input.lastInput", function() {
  alert('d');
});
$("body").append(input);
​
```

[Example -2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut3Jp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("focus", 'textarea, input', function(){
       console.log('d');
    })​
});
```